Why the refractive index difference in a fiber waveguide between the core and cladding in a fiber has to be small? $n_1 - n_0 = 0.01$
I have seen this in every textbook on fiber waveguides. Why is the refractive index difference so small? Isn't it easier to have the difference larger because with a large refractive index difference you can excite at larger angles and achieve Total Internal Reflection easily.

Well, one reason could be that you only would like to have a single or a few addressable guided modes in a narrow wavelength range to be supported by your fiber. If you increase the reflective index contrast, the number of guided modes will increase.


The index difference (~0.02) works.  You can create a bound single mode just fine.

There are consequences to using a much higher index difference. Most notably, you need to add dopants to increase the index and this will increase the loss.

Also, if the index difference is too high, then the single mode will be tightly bound and it'll be more difficult to prevent higher-order modes.


